# Flash action script3 problem, can't change property name

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm not very good at AS3, but i imported XML to my flash and i want to change it dynamically from drop down menu. I need to change "**THISPLACE**" in script below with simple string, how do i do that? Thanks for help :)

```
function uzkrautXML():void
{
    var XMLURLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    XMLURLLoader.load(new URLRequest(xmlArdesas));
    XMLURLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
}

function processXML(event:Event):void
{
    var theXMLData:XML = new XML(XMLURLLoader.data);
    visoSk = theXMLData.THISPLACE.length();

    for (var i:Number = 0; i <visoSk; i++)
    {
        skArray.push(theXMLData.THISPLACE[i]);
    }

    uzkrautSkelbimus();
}
```

I know there are mistakes in code, but dont mind it, i need to know just how replace that plase

Comment: Can you give a sample of the xml that you're loading? Are you trying to change values within it or the structure? Check out here for a nice tutorial : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/filtering_data_e4x.html

Comment: When you name your objects in AS3 I'd recommend using camelcase. I'd suggest changing `XMLURLLoader` to `xmlURLLoader` or `xmlUrlLoader` or even just `urlLoader`. Also you might want to name your event handlers using this formula on[object][event type], e.g. `onXMLURLLoaderComplete` or `onXmlUrlLoaderComplete`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use child() method of top level XML class.

```
function processXML(event:Event):void
{

    var theXMLData:XML = new XML(XMLURLLoader.data);
    theXMLData.ignoreWhite = true;
    visoSk = theXMLData.child("THISPLACE_NAME").length();

    for (var i:Number = 0; i <visoSk; i++)
    {
        skArray.push(theXMLData.child("THISPLACE_NAME")[i]);
    }
    uzkrautSkelbimus();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: THanks, this helps, but now i have another problem:

i wnt to write that line like this     :       


visoSk = theXMLData.THISPLACE.anyName.length();



what shoud i do then?

Comment: Second question was stupid... don't mind it :D You saved me man, THANK YOU VERY MUCH ;)

Comment: You're very welcome, @CGpro. Don't you want to upvote the answer and accept it?